# Update Manager failed with "the package catalog has broken" error

Tags: package-management, updates, update-manager

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 from a live DVD. Then went for updating through Update Manager. It downloaded everything. During installing them the update manager crashed. It showed the error message:

> The package catalog has broken. Installing or removing
>   software is not possible until the package catalog is repaired.

However opting for repair didn't work and it continued showing the notification obstinately. I was undone.

Please show me how I can repair it.

**@int_ua**

apt-get update -f did not work. Problem still persists.

**@freecode**

dpkg --configure -a did not remove the broken package. Nevertheless, I found details that the problem might be due to some third-party package. Now, how to check whether I am using any third-party package and if so how to disable them?

Comment: Do you get the same result if you run `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: open your dash and type "software sources" - you can find any third-party ppa's installed there - untick them to disable them.  Rerun `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` to check if you have resolved your problem.

Comment: @fossfreedomAfter disabling them and running apt-get update && apt-get upgrade I found that the problem is due to unmet dependencies of evolution-data-server : Depends: evolution-data-server-common (= 3.2.2-0ubuntu1~oneiric) but 3.2.0-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libedataserverui-3.0-1 : Depends: evolution-data-server-common (>= 3.2.2) but 3.2.0-0ubuntu1 is installed. But now, how to remove this unmet dependency. Update manager is not allowing removing or installing anything. I do not know how to tackle it in the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

You can always try going to the command line and trying this command:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and simply allow the package manager to repair itself. That will usually do the job.

Hope that helps. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and solved it:
I ran software-center in a terminal and looking at the error messages, I did:

```
sudo chmod a+r /var/cache/apt-xapian-index/index.1/*
sudo chmod a+r /var/lib/apt-xapian-index/*
```

The command

```
dpkg -l
```

produced an error mesage, I solved that with

```
sudo chmod a+r /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch
```

And now software-center is running as it should.